# How to Assign Datasources and IncludeTemplatesForSelection with Helix

Tags: helix

I am not shure how to do it "right" because the solution that this works would be to use the "MetaData Keyword" instead of the "_Keyword" as "IncludeTemplatesForSelection" but then I would "reference" from my feature to the project layer but as datasource I've set allready a Guid from "sitecore/content/s.../..DotCom/Global/MetaData Keywords"

does it give here a right and "wrong" solution or what would be the right approach?

[image]

Comment: It would not work since when you add your 2nd web site, your metadata would come from your 1st site.

Comment: I will have to find it, but what you want to use is the $site (from SXA) and the site: (from Habitat) in your field datasource. This will allow you to find the metadata path from the current site. The $site code will be in Foundation, so that is Helix compliant. Imagine this code, but where {token} was $site and got replaced with your site root item path. https://asmagin.com/2014/06/22/sitecore-extending-field-datasource-queries-with-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using a query to solve the multisite problem and using a Multilist as Type

the new source Query is:

```
query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename='Site Root']/Global//*[@@templatename ='MetaData Keyword']
```